Factoring a symmetric positive definite matrix
Suppose $A$ is symmetric positive definite, can we always find another matrix $B$ such that $A=BB^T$?
Related question: I've seen people use square root in the context of symmetric positive definite matrices, when does it make sense, and what exactly it refers to?

The answer to your second question also the answer to your first.
The Spectral Theorem says that any symmetric real matrix can be orthogonally diagonalized, say as $A=U^TDU$ with $D$ diagonal, $U$ unitary. Since you are assuming $A$ is positive definite, all of the diagonal entries of $D$ are positive.
So in fact, let $\sqrt{D}$ be the diagonal matrix formed by taking the (positive) square root of each diagonal entry of $D$. This is well-defined, and we have $\sqrt{D}\sqrt{D} = D$.
Then $B = U^T\sqrt{D}U$ is symmetric and positive-definite. Further, $$B^2 = B^TB = (U^T\sqrt{D}U)(U^T\sqrt{D}U) = U^T\sqrt{D}\sqrt{D}U = U^TDU = A$$ where we use the fact that $U$ is unitary so $UU^T = I$.

You mean $A=UDU^T$, right?

@CroCo Doesn't matter. The transpose of a unitary real matrix is still unitary.
